# How do I create a form for an associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `company` model and a `bank_account` model.

`company has_many bank_accounts` and `bank_account belongs_to company`.

I have a route `companies/:company_id/bank_accounts/new` which generates a form:

```
<%= form_for @bank_account do |form| %>
 (form elements here)
<% end %>
```

But when I get to that page, I get: `undefined method bank_accounts_path`

Here's my resource routes in routes.rb:

```
  resources :companies do
    resources :bank_accounts, module: :companies
  end
```

and my nested bank_account_controller.rb in controllers/companies/

I need my form to post the entered data to the create action. Ruby should know this already right because I'm in the new action? But clearly it doesn't recognise the route.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: You better use `form_with` which is the new helper for forms. And write it like this : `form_with model: [@company, @bank_account] do |form|`

Comment: Thanks Maxence, I was messing around while waiting for a response here and used form_with and done a few other things and now it works. I'm gonna post my solution now. For clarification, can you help me understand what the difference between form_for and form_with? Should I always use the latter?

Comment: `form_with` merges both `form_for` and `form_tag` : you can create a form with a model or without a model in a single helper. It is the right helper to use, others are deprecated.

Comment: I see, thank you so much! That's valuable insight. I feel like it should just be removed as a helper if form_with covers both.

Comment: Also, as you seem interested, you can just use `model: @bank_account` and add an extra param `url` with the right nested route to your bank_accounts controller. It should work. Passing an array as the model, makes the helper infer the right route by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was changing a few things to match a similar model for company contacts. I knew these we're the same concept in my application so the same routing and form should work.

First I moved my nested bank_account_controller.rb out of companies and just placed it in app/controllers.

I moved all my bank_account views out of the nested bank_account folder inside views/companies to just app/views/bank_accounts.

I then removed the module companies from my routes.rb so I just had resources `:bank_accounts` within my companies resources.

Finally, I changed the form_for to: `form_with (model: [@company, @bank_account], local: true) do |form| %>`

Forms constantly trip me up as a somewhat newbie to RoR. I need to understand better what the difference is between for and with :)

Answer (score 0):

You have nested resource, therefore you need

```
<%= form_for [@company, @bank_account] do |form| %>
```

Comment: I'm sure this would've worked too mechnicov. Is there a better practice path to take here between form_with or form_for in the situation where I need to create an instance of an associated model.

Comment: *I'm sure this would've worked too* -- did you try it? You can use both `form_with` and `form_for`

Comment: I didn't but, to do so, I would have to revert the changes I made and I'm of the mind now that "if it ain't broke don't fix it"

Comment: Hmm, if you didn't, why did you wrote, that you are sure? This helper works as helper from you answer